# Laravel - Building a JS library using typescript and Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript

I have a function that I've written with Typescript that I'd like to make available as a library.

I'm using Laravel Mix and babel ts loader to transpile the .ts files into .js files.

However, when I cannot use the functions even when the file is found:

```
<script type="module">
    import getCardInfo from '/js/main.js';
    console.log(getCardInfo)
</script>
```

The error received is:

```
The requested module '/js/main.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

resources/cardActions.ts:

```
export default function getCardInfo() {
    console.log("getting card info");
}
```

My webpack.mix.js is:

```
mix.ts('resources/cardActions.ts', 'public/js')
mix.webpackConfig({
    entry: './public/js/cardActions.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'js/main.js',
        libraryTarget: 'window'
    }
})
```

Comment: `import {getCardInfo} from '/js/main.js';` try this import statement

Comment: Unfortunately, same deal: `The requested module '/js/main.js' does not provide an export named 'createNewItem'`

Comment: can you please provide your .ts file content. I think you forgot to export the `getCardInfo ` function there.

Comment: Sure. updated,

The issue is that I see the function in the compiled main.js, but I just cannot use the function

Comment: Could you solve this?, I'm trying to use Vue with typescript in Laravel and I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You must let this code through webpack,

```
<script type="module">
    import getCardInfo from '/js/main.js';
    console.log(getCardInfo)
</script>
```

not `mix.ts('resources/cardActions.ts', 'public/js')`

is  `mix.ts('resources/Your_script_import_code_file.ts', 'public/js')`

then webpack can both compile import_file and export_file！

Comment: it'll be great if you could explain your solution as well. it is pretty unreadable as of now.